# ASP.NET MVC Model First Many To Many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-model-first

I have some problems working with model first many to many relationship. Since I created many-many relationship between `Town` and `Author` via interface builder it created table `TownAuthor` with keys `Towns_TownID` and `Authors_AuthorID` but I want that just to be called `TownID` and `AuthorID`, how do I change that?

In Code first I would use that modelBuilder configuration in Context but I have no idea how to do this via model first...

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the names of these columns in the Entity Designer DDL script (which is generated from the EDMX file and has ModelName.edmx.sql name) before executing it.

```
-- Creating table 'TownAuthor'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TownAuthor] (
    [TownID] int  NOT NULL,
    [AuthorID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```